# Metaphorically speaking who is closer: humans to ants or humans to G-d?

Tags: theology

Following my theological quest on the differences between the Maimonedian and Zoharian approach to G-d's anthropomorphism,

how would both schools see this question: intellectually and spiritually, are we closer to ants or to G-d?

Comment: Is there anything written from those of either school that you have found to suggest that they’d think that the created (i.e., us/humans) would be closer intellectually to a creator (G-d) that we are unable to physically perceive in this physical world than to another of G-d’s creations (Ants)?  Just curious. I have not downvoted.

Comment: @Akiva___ IMHO Rambam presented a [*very frightening for his time*] view that G-d is so immensely huge and "distant", we're closer to ants, but Zohar restored the human touch, bringing G-d much closer to us.

Comment: G-d can be everywhere and is not subject to time or any limitations.  Humans and ants are the opposite.  I’m not sure how humans can be closer to G-d except for the fact that we were given free will and an ability to understand his existence and animals were not.

Comment: Also haven't downvoted, but it's hard for me to imagine how anyone could argue that "intellectually and spiritually" humans are closer to God. It seems obvious to me that humans are far more similar to ants.

Comment: Also, @AlBerko isn't your comment an answer to the question? If you think you know the answer, why are you asking it?

Comment: @Daniel I ask because this is how Torah learning goes, you might think that you know the answer, but the truth is out there.

Comment: @Akiva___ I think this is exactly what would ants say of us - they are unable to perceive our world.

Answer (score 0):

Even like The Rambam, we are infinitely closer to ants. Ants, for one, have a form. HaShem doesn't. The Rambam holds that thoughts can't really encapsulate HaShem, much like our power the taste cannot "taste" the number six. (As an aside, the Baal HaTanya wires near the beginning of the Tanya that what The Rambam says that "HaShem and his knowledge are one" is only true בעולם האצילות but cannot be said of the העולם דאדם קדמון"). This is central to Judaism.

Here's a link to a summary of the 13 Principles of Faith as codified by the Rambam. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm

I see from your comments above that you have started to read The Zohar. Perhaps this is the place to recommend to anyone to learn Das Tevunos by the Ramchal and the the maamorim at the  beginning of Shaarei Ramchal (compiled by Rav Chaim Friedlander) for some the proper introductory knowledge required to begin to start to slightly understand what we have read in the Zohar. I would also like to ask you mechila, because my previous version of this paragraph was condescending. Sorry! (Unfortunately my am haaretzus gets the better of me!)

Comment: בעולם הרציחות? Please doublecheck your spelling. Only the first paragraph is relevant to the question and it adds nothing to what's already been said. Your answer is unclear and unsourced. I would greatly appreciate if you develop the idea of your first lines

Comment: You are correct in that learning Kaballah will strengthen  HaShem in our lives and bring him closer to us but He is still in a completely different really to all created brings i.e. everything you can imagine. Perhaps I will be marchiv next week.